# jQuery form submitting script does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I try to prevent a form submitting, with the following script, but it always does. I have even tried `preventDefault()` on document load, but it does not work.

```
$("form").submit(function() {
      if ($("input").eq(3).val() == $("input").eq(4).val()) {
            $("span").text("Validated...").show();
        return true;
      }

      $("span").text("Passwords do not match!").show().fadeOut(1000);
      return false;
});
```

Comment: `return true` will cause the form to submit. Your code looks fine.

Comment: @KevinB
I know right? But it does not work! Maybe something's wrong with my server/browser(Chrome).

Comment: For debugging, return false in both cases and alert or console.log at each to know which one was reached. More than likely your if statement conditional isn't selecting the correct input elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for this to close I think I have found something, but it's absurd at best. My functions work when they are in a $(document).ready. Why? I would be glad to listen to your advice.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("form").submit(function() {
      if ($("input").eq(3).val() == $("input").eq(4).val()) {
            $("span").text("Validated...").show();
        return true;
      }

      $("span").text("Passwords do not match!").show().fadeOut(1000);
      return false;
});

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
      if ($("input").eq(3).val() == $("input").eq(4).val()) {
            $("span").text("Validated...").show();
      }
      else{
        $("span").text("Passwords do not match!").show().fadeOut(1000);
        e.preventDefault();
      }
});
```

You need to use `preventDefault()` to cancel the action. Note the parameter `e` that I added to the anonymous function call.

Comment: It still submits. Weird things... Also can you elaborate what the 'e' stands for?

Comment: return `false` from a jQuery event handler already does `preventDefault()` for you.  This doesn't change the submit behavior from OP's code.

Comment: @Peter Your validation logic must be evaluating to true then, so it's never getting to the `preventDefault()` line. `e` is just shorthand for `event`. You can name it whatever you want, but it is the event object that contains a number of properties related to the event.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, or the way I normally go about this is like this:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // form never fires unless I want it to

    if( condition == true ) {
        $(this).submit();
    } else {
        //Don't submit
    }
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) is a great explanation of why preventDefault() > return false